# Connect Two Android Phones with Java Server

Tags: java, android, sockets

Which is the best way to connect 2 android phones in the internet with a Java Server?

I'm making an game form android. At this moment i have the single player working. But now i have two use an Java server to play online games.

Which is the best way to communicate with 2 phones ?

Most difficult action is send information of client1 to the Server and Server redirect this information to client 2.

Anyone can help me?

Regards

Comment: It is going to depend a lot on the type/size/quantity of the data. Can you tell us more about what type of game?

Comment: The game that i'm implementing is a multiplayer quizz game where each player answer to an certain number of questions and in the final who have more correct answers win. So the data that i want sent isn't bigger. Thank u

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use either SOAP or REST, using Jax-RS (rest) or Java-WS (SOAP).

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/index-jsp-137004.html
http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/giepu.html

Here is one way, assuming your game has some turn based interface, and you want to do is have a create game/join game or a create game with user style interface.

1. When the game starts, connect to the server using one of
   the above techniques (soap/rest) to let the server know you are
   there.
2. Then have one client say create a new game.  This will tell the
   server to create the game.
3. The other client will tell the server to list games.  Then on
   the client, choose a game to join.  Then tell the server of the game
   choice, so that it knows to add you.
4. The phone that started the game, should poll the server to see if
   another user joined the game.  Eventually some will join. (there are
   other ways to handle this, but polling is very easy to do)
5. Have all players in the game poll to find out if the game started, then
   go, once they have all joined.

Answer (score 0):

There sure isn't a best way to do that. There are some techniques.

But what I would do is to create a long, unclosed http request from both of the clients to the server and then when something happens the clients get responses from the server. This is called [Comet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29), but I never implemented that by myself. There sure is an Android implementation (or just a Java  implementation).